# Node + PhantomJS | Return after page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I have a NodeJS + Phantom project, and I have the following function:

```
function isLogged(page) {
    var logged = false;
    page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector(".login") != null;
    }, function(bl) {
        console.log("1");
        logged = bl;
    });
    console.log("2");
    return logged;
}
```

But this function prints "2" before "1". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a bridge between node.js and PhantomJS. PhantomJS runs as a separate process which means that every communication is done asynchronously. You can't `return` a result that is calculated asynchronously. The easy solution is to use a callback function:

```
function isLogged(page, callback) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        return !!document.querySelector(".login");
    }, callback);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
isLogged(page, function(res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

This won't `return` anything.

Comment: But the function will return false as all

Comment: Yes, that's because you can't return something that is calculated asynchronously. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for the same problem in AJAX requests.

Comment: Can you tell me what to do to make the function work?